# Corrupted lines in a large csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am using python to extract lines from a csv file into a list, using the csv module.
The csv file is fairly large, about 45,000 lines, and it seems like some of the lines are corrupted.
When employing python's csv.reader module, it only reads about 1000 lines, and then get to a corrupted line and stops reading, without even giving an error message.
Because the file is very large, it is very hard to change it manually.  I did it once for that first corrupted line, and it did manage to read 500 more lines, and then it apparently reached another corrupted line and stopped.
I'll be glad to get ideas on how to deal with this, since opening the file and editing it is impossible due to its size (~500 MB).

Thank you.

Comment: What is the nature of the corruption? Could you post an example line, and maybe some good ones?

Comment: Any particular code that you have? An example of a "corrupted" line would be great as well.

Comment: In which way is it corrupt? Missing data? missing separator?

Comment: can you share some of your code!!

Comment: @user0815 He is using the built in parser `csv.reader`.

Answer (score 0):

***If*** it's safe to assume that each line is an entry, you could try splitting the file in chunks of ~500 lines for example and once you notice that the number of parsed entries is not that of the lines, you can inspect that smaller subset, and so on.

For example:

```
for i, line in enumerate(original_file):
    chunk_file.write(line+'\n')
    if i == 500: break
```

Then parse the `chunk_file`, see how much data is parsed. If equal, go on; if not, it's corrupted there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying something like:

```
with open('largeFile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    for k, line in enumerate(csvfile):
        row = line.strip().split(',')
        if len(row) != <YourExpectedNumberOfColumns>:
            print(k,row)
```

This stands the chance of mostly printing your problematic lines, which might help you focus your debugging efforts.